# Modifying Linux I/O schedulers

Tags: io, linux-kernel, scheduler

I want to modify Linux i/o schedulers.

Is there anyway to do so beside compiling whole kernel again?

Are I/O schedulers kernel modules and can I just make kernel module and load it and use it as an I/O scheduler?

Answer (score 2):

Linux has a modular IO scheduler infrastructure - you can write a new IO scheduler as a kernel module, load it into the kernel, use it for specific (or all) block IO devices and then remove it.

See here how to select an existing IO scheduler. For writing new ones you'll have to read the source code I'm afraid :-)

Comment: i know how to make kernel modules (very simple ones) how can i just copy a simple io scheduler like noop from source and add modify it and make kernel use this scheduler? is there any tutorial for that available?

Comment: I'm afraid it is more complicated then that, but the code sits unders linux/block/*-iosched.c in the Linux kernel source tree.

Comment: i can modify that code, compile it, load it as a kernel module but how kernel should know this module is a scheduler and show it in /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler?

Comment: @Rezass: When loading, the scheduler module's init_module function registers itself with the kernel and the scheduler framework as available scheduler.

Comment: finally i copy pasted noop-iosched.c addded a for to it compile it using makefile load it using insmod and changing /sys/block/sda/queue/schduler to my custom scheduler and DONE:D thanks to all who helped me

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask these questions, then you should not try modifying I/O schedulers. They're some of the most delicate things of the Linux kernel. To be able to do usefull I/O scheduler development requires enough understanding of the topics you asked here, that asking here is indication you don't understand those topics enough.

Comment: I'm not trying to develop io schedulers.
for a project i just need to edit one of io schedulers(even add 1 varible and ++ it somewhere)

Comment: @Rezass: The problem is, that this will most likely break it. Well, you will have to compile the kernel for it anyway (you need a proper build tree).

Comment: that's the point somehow:D
breaking scheduler is also shows something changed in it and that's the project's point.
so there isn't anyway other than compiling whole kernel?

Comment: @Rezass: You'll not get around it. But compiling a kernel is not terribly difficult.

Comment: it's not difficult. i know how i should to it but it needs some time and i wish i could skip compile time:D

Comment: @Rezass: Yes, about 5 minutes on my laptop. Maybe 15 if all features are enabled, all drivers selected.